# Django url regexp

Tags: regex, django

I am very new to regexp and have some difficulties right now:
I had a regexp

```
url(r'^users/\w+/$', views.user)
```

Right now I want to change the alphanumerical 'w+' to alphanumerical plus dot char.

I tried

```
url(r'^users/([a-zA-Z0-9\.])/$', views.user)
```

And its not working. I get a 404 page.
 Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Your regex only matches a *single* alphanumerical plus dot char... See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/rV0yM0/1

Comment: What does "not working" mean? what does it match/not match that you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

`url(r'^users/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/$', views.user)`

We dont use`\` to escape `.` inside a character class. So to match a character inside character class, we dont escape it. Ex: `[.]`

Answer (score -1):

```
url(r'^users/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/$', views.user)
```

Add `+`.

Comment: `[\.]` inside a character class will match either a \ or a `.`

Comment: @shiva A backslash will escape the next character, regardless of if that character actually needs escaping. In this case, both `[.]` and `[\.]` will only match a literal `.`. The only way to match a literal backslash is by escaping the backslash, i.e. `[\\.]`.

Comment: @knbk Thanks. I didnt know that.